# why date() function get wrong month?

Tags: php, date, time

I am using **date()** function to get the month and year from timestamp ..

it should return ***2019-10*** and when i test it on here : https://3v4l.org/uH5Gt

it get correct result

but when i use the same code in my project .. it gets 2019-09 .. it gets the previous month!!

why that ?!

this is my code :

```
$start    = 1569888000;
echo date("Y-m", $start);
```

Comment: You know about __timezones__?

Comment: yes, but even my timezone get 2019-10 .. also i test now on localhost and get correct result

Comment: Server has __it's own timezone__. https://3v4l.org/FZkO3

Comment: Note for other people looking around: `(time_t)1569888000` is `2019-10-01T00:00:00Z`

Answer (score 0):

Below would return each of day.

```
echo date("Y-n-j", strtotime("first day of previous month"));
echo date("Y-n-j", strtotime("last day of previous month"));
```

If you are not sure for timezone setting, try to below code

```
// set the default timezone to use. Available since PHP 5.1
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$start    = 1569888000;
echo date("Y-m", $start);
```